# networkx: Graph.nodes() inconsistent behaviour?

Tags: python, networkx

From what I undestand G.nodes() or G.nodes(False) should return a list of nodes. However I find that while this works:

```
G = nx.watts_strogatz_graph(1000, 20, 0)
random.choice(G.nodes())
```

this doesn't:

```
G = nx.grid_graph([20,20])
random.choice(G.nodes())
->
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1016, in mtrand.RandomState.choice (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:7850)
ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional
```

When I check the shape of G.nodes() in the 2. case, it's always (400,2) regardless if I use G.nodes(False) or G.nodes(True). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how `random` is defined. If `random` is the module from the standard library, then:

```
import random
random.choice(G.nodes())
```

will work. If `random` is `numpy.random`, then

```
from numpy import random
random.choice(G.nodes())
```

will raise

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/random/mtrand.so in mtrand.RandomState.choice (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:7850)()

ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional
```

Note the path in the error message refers to `numpy/random`.

---

To avoid this error in the future, never use `from numpy import random`, since it masks the module of the same name from the standard library.

For the same reason, never use `from numpy import *`, since it also masks such commonly used builtins as `max`, `min`, `sum`, `any` and `all`.

Comment: As you've correctly assumed, I was using "from scipy import  *". I'll be aware of the risks from now on. Thanks a lot!